# Netbeans regex - Find and Replace (Ctrl + H)

Tags: c, regex, netbeans, replace

I'm exploring regex, but I simply could not achieve exactly what I want yet. I'm using NetBeans and I need to swap all `strncpy(... , sizeof(x))` to `strncpy(... , sizeof(x) -1 )`, i.e, add the `"-1"` between the last parenthesis.

An example should be:

```
strncpy(data->error, t_result[ID(data->modulo)].status, sizeof(data->error)); //need below
strncpy(data->error, t_result[ID(data->modulo)].status, sizeof(data->error) - 1);
```

Comment: [`(strncpy\(.*?sizeof\([^)]*\))` replace with `$1 - 1`](https://regex101.com/r/wVqYke/1)?

Comment: thanks, if you want to write that in the answer, I kindly accept this as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/wVqYke/1)

```
(strncpy\(.*?sizeof\([^)]*\))
```

- `(strncpy\(.*?sizeof\([^)]*\))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `strncpy\(` Matches `strncpy(` literally
  - `.*?` Matches any character any number of times, but as few as possible
  - `sizeof\(` Matches `sizeof(` literally
  - `[^)]*` Matches any character except `)` any number of times
  - `\)` Matches `)` literally

Replacement `$1 - 1`

Result in:

```
strncpy(data->error, t_result[ID(data->modulo)].status, sizeof(data->error) - 1);
```